# Recent Software update

Tags: system, updates

I love Elementary OS. Just installed the recent update. Did the reboot and got the "Mountall could not conect to Plymouth" screen froze at this point. I was able to open another tty and removed the NVIDIA drivers but left nouveau intact. On reboot the system can't find nouveau and the screen freezes. I cannot get to another tty. I can get to recovery mode and system prompt # via recovery but get errors about files being locked apt-get update gets errors about being locked. I don't want to start from scratch re-installing elementary. Any advice on how to get my elementary back.